# The meaning of "superior bearer" and "his bundle"

Tags: meaning

“Nothin’ like havin’ a father before you,” said the Major. “I’m a parvenu with my chaps. I’ve only been twenty years in the regiment, and my revered parent he was a simple squire. There’s no getting at the bottom of a Bhil’s mind. Now, **why is the superior bearer that young Chinn brought with him fleeing across country with his bundle?”** He stepped into the verandah, and shouted after the man—a typical new-joined subaltern’s servant who speaks English and cheats in proportion.

This id from "The Tomb of His Ancestors" by Rudyard Kipling.
http://www.telelib.com/authors/K/KiplingRudyard/prose/TheDaysWork/ancestors.html

I can't understand the meaning of....
"why is the superior bearer that young Chinn brought with him fleeing across country with his bundle?”

What is "superior bearer" and "his bundle"?

I am glad if someone would kindly teach  me.

Comment: He is a new-joined subaltern’s servant, and his bundle contains his possessions.

Comment: From the context I would guess "superior" means _conceited/snooty_. (This is difficult English! Thank you for the link: I've just read the whole story. I like Kipling very much.)